# Ranking all features in order using scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to sort all features in order using `scikit-learn` [f_regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression) and [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest). The method works well if the number of ranked features `k` is smaller than the total number of features `n`. However, if I set `k = n` then the output from `SelectKBest` will be in the same order as the original feature array. How can I sort all features in order according to their importance?

The code is below:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_regression

n = len(training_features.columns)

selector = SelectKBest(f_regression, k = n)
selector.fit(training_features.values, training_targets.values[:, 0])

k_best_features = list(training_features.columns[selector.get_support(indices = True)])
```

Comment: `selector.get_support()` only returns the selected features, not their importances or order. So what do you mean by `"The method works well if the number of ranked features k is smaller than the total"`??

Comment: I see. I thought the order of the returned vector was their importance. I want to get the k features in order according to their importance.

Comment: From all the features, the top k features are selected based on the importance, but from the selected k features, you cannot say which is more important. If you need that, you need to use the `selector.scores_` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this solution:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression

k = 10    # number of best features to obtain

scores, _ = f_regression(training_features.values, training_targets.values[:, 0])
indices = np.argsort(scores)[::-1]
k_best_features = list(training_features.columns.values[indices[0:k]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinking sorting the featuers, with respect to the scores given by `f_regression`, can be generated using

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(feature_names= training_features.columns , scores = selector.scores_))\
    .sort_values('scores',ascending = False)
```